# Can't hide Jquery DataTable vertical scrollbar on thead

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery DataTables and bootstrap.

On my thead appears a disabled vertical scrollbar like this:

[image]

I'm trying to get rid off of that scrollbar, but without success.

```
//Fixed Columns (Freeze Panel)
        $(function () {            
            var table = $('#grdAfiliados').DataTable({
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    // Disable scrolling in Head
                    $('.dataTables_scrollHead').css({                        
                        'overflow-x': 'hidden !important',
                        'overflow-y': 'hidden !important'                        
                    });

                    // Disable TBODY srcoll bars
                    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css({
                        'overflow-y': 'scroll',
                        'overflow-x': 'hidden',
                        'border': '0'
                    });

                    // Enable TFOOT scoll bars
                    $('.dataTables_scrollFoot').css('overflow', 'auto');

                    // Sync TFOOT scrolling with TBODY
                    $('.dataTables_scrollFoot').on('scroll', function () {
                        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
                    });
                },
                scrollY: "500px",
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 1
                }
            });
        });
```

**EDIT:**

I realize that the problem appears when using "fixedColumns" parameter.

Comment: If you can reproduce in a Plunker or JSFiddle, I'd be happy to help - I'm just not seeing it when I try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide the div that holds that scroll elements like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
.DTFC_RightBodyLiner{
 opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Step 1: //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js<br/>
   //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

```
Step 2:

    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Extn.</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger</td>
                    <td>Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                    <td>5421</td>
                    <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett</td>
                    <td>Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                    <td>8422</td>
                    <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton</td>
                    <td>Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                    <td>1562</td>
                    <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric</td>
                    <td>Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                    <td>6224</td>
                    <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi</td>
                    <td>Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                    <td>5407</td>
                    <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle</td>
                    <td>Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                    <td>4804</td>
                    <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod</td>
                    <td>Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                    <td>9608</td>
                    <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rhona</td>
                    <td>Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>2010/10/14</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                    <td>6200</td>
                    <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Colleen</td>
                    <td>Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>2009/09/15</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                    <td>2360</td>
                    <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sonya</td>
                    <td>Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2008/12/13</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                    <td>1667</td>
                    <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jena</td>
                    <td>Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2008/12/19</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                    <td>3814</td>
                    <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td>9497</td>
                    <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Charde</td>
                    <td>Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>2008/10/16</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                    <td>6741</td>
                    <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Haley</td>
                    <td>Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2012/12/18</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                    <td>3597</td>
                    <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tatyana</td>
                    <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>2010/03/17</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                    <td>1965</td>
                    <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael</td>
                    <td>Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2012/11/27</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                    <td>1581</td>
                    <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Paul</td>
                    <td>Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2010/06/09</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                    <td>3059</td>
                    <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gloria</td>
                    <td>Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2009/04/10</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                    <td>1721</td>
                    <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bradley</td>
                    <td>Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2012/10/13</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                    <td>2558</td>
                    <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dai</td>
                    <td>Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>2012/09/26</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                    <td>2290</td>
                    <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jenette</td>
                    <td>Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2011/09/03</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                    <td>1937</td>
                    <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yuri</td>
                    <td>Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>2009/06/25</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                    <td>6154</td>
                    <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caesar</td>
                    <td>Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2011/12/12</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                    <td>8330</td>
                    <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Doris</td>
                    <td>Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2010/09/20</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                    <td>3023</td>
                    <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Angelica</td>
                    <td>Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/10/09</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                    <td>5797</td>
                    <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin</td>
                    <td>Joyce</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>42</td>
                    <td>2010/12/22</td>
                    <td>$92,575</td>
                    <td>8822</td>
                    <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer</td>
                    <td>Chang</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2010/11/14</td>
                    <td>$357,650</td>
                    <td>9239</td>
                    <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brenden</td>
                    <td>Wagner</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2011/06/07</td>
                    <td>$206,850</td>
                    <td>1314</td>
                    <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fiona</td>
                    <td>Green</td>
                    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>48</td>
                    <td>2010/03/11</td>
                    <td>$850,000</td>
                    <td>2947</td>
                    <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shou</td>
                    <td>Itou</td>
                    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>2011/08/14</td>
                    <td>$163,000</td>
                    <td>8899</td>
                    <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michelle</td>
                    <td>House</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2011/06/02</td>
                    <td>$95,400</td>
                    <td>2769</td>
                    <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Suki</td>
                    <td>Burks</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                    <td>2009/10/22</td>
                    <td>$114,500</td>
                    <td>6832</td>
                    <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prescott</td>
                    <td>Bartlett</td>
                    <td>Technical Author</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/05/07</td>
                    <td>$145,000</td>
                    <td>3606</td>
                    <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin</td>
                    <td>Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2008/10/26</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                    <td>2860</td>
                    <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Martena</td>
                    <td>Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/03/09</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                    <td>8240</td>
                    <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unity</td>
                    <td>Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/12/09</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                    <td>5384</td>
                    <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Howard</td>
                    <td>Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/12/16</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                    <td>7031</td>
                    <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hope</td>
                    <td>Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2010/02/12</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                    <td>6318</td>
                    <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vivian</td>
                    <td>Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>62</td>
                    <td>2009/02/14</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                    <td>9422</td>
                    <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Timothy</td>
                    <td>Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2008/12/11</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                    <td>7580</td>
                    <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson</td>
                    <td>Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td>2008/09/26</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                    <td>1042</td>
                    <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Olivia</td>
                    <td>Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2011/02/03</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                    <td>2120</td>
                    <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bruno</td>
                    <td>Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>38</td>
                    <td>2011/05/03</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                    <td>6222</td>
                    <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sakura</td>
                    <td>Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2009/08/19</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                    <td>9383</td>
                    <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thor</td>
                    <td>Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2013/08/11</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                    <td>8327</td>
                    <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finn</td>
                    <td>Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/07/07</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                    <td>2927</td>
                    <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Serge</td>
                    <td>Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2012/04/09</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                    <td>8352</td>
                    <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zenaida</td>
                    <td>Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2010/01/04</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                    <td>7439</td>
                    <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zorita</td>
                    <td>Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>2012/06/01</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                    <td>4389</td>
                    <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer</td>
                    <td>Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2013/02/01</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                    <td>3431</td>
                    <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cara</td>
                    <td>Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/12/06</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                    <td>3990</td>
                    <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hermione</td>
                    <td>Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2011/03/21</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                    <td>1016</td>
                    <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lael</td>
                    <td>Greer</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2009/02/27</td>
                    <td>$103,500</td>
                    <td>6733</td>
                    <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jonas</td>
                    <td>Alexander</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2010/07/14</td>
                    <td>$86,500</td>
                    <td>8196</td>
                    <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shad</td>
                    <td>Decker</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/11/13</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                    <td>6373</td>
                    <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael</td>
                    <td>Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>2011/06/27</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                    <td>5384</td>
                    <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna</td>
                    <td>Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td>4226</td>
                    <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

Step 3:
    <style>
    div.dataTables_wrapper {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
```

Step 4:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "scrollX": true
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: Doesn't help. The problem appears when using "fixedColumns" parameters.